# Which structure is most similar to the BLoC pattern in Flutter on the iOS side?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, state-management

I am using BLoC pattern for state management in Flutter. Is there a structure in iOS where we can manage events and states as in BLoC? Which one can I get used to more comfortably, which is more similar to BLoC?

Comment: Can you link to something about BLoC and maybe I can help

Comment: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture

Comment: A fundamental question is whether you are using UIKit or SwiftUI.  SwiftUI has a declarative style with bindings, so your BLOC looks to me much like a view model.  You can use `ObservableObject` and `@Published` properties.  You can also use `Combine` directly, which is what these are built on.  If you are using UIKit, this is an MVC paradigm.  It doesn't really have binding, but you can introduce something or write something to do this.  Again, `Combine` is probably an tool you could use.